# Conditionally include macOS-only code in a SwiftUI (Mac Catalyst) project?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I am writing an app that runs on both iOS and macOS, using Mac Catalyst with Swift.

I want to set a property that is *only* available on macOS but I cannot find a way using `#available` or `@available` to prevent the compiler from including this line of code in the iOS builds:

This syntax does not work because the *mandatory* trailing `*` includes all iOS versions.

```
if #available(macCatalyst 13.0, *) {
    view.showsZoomControls = true
}
```

I tried adding a nonsense version of iOS using `iOS 999` but that didn't work either, because the property is marked strictly unavailable in iOS.

Using `@available` there's a longhand syntax using `introduced:` that allows per-OS versions to be specified and requires a separate `@available` entry per OS but I can't see any way to use that.  It seems you can't use `@available` on a block of code.

Is there really no sane way to do this?

For reference, the definition of this specific property is:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL showsZoomControls
    API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.9), macCatalyst(13.0)) 
    API_UNAVAILABLE(ios, watchos, tvos);
```

Answer (score 4):

Crisis averted - it seems that `available` is the wrong hammer for this nail.

What's working for me now is the much simpler:

```
#if os(macOS)
view.showsZoomControls = true
#endif
```

Comment: Would not available work with macOS instead of macCatalyst?

Comment: @cora I tried that too, with no success.  The catchall behaviour of the required `*` seems to be the real stumbling point, but I'm probably using the wrong tool.

Comment: What about wrapping the view with the check in AnyView?

Answer (score 4):

You can identify/restrict Mac Catalyst with target environment

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
view.showsZoomControls = true
#endif
```